# In AWS EMR Jupyter Notebook, how to change the user from livy to hadoop

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, livy

I have created a AWS EMR Cluster and uploaded,

```
sparkify_log_small.json
```

And created a EMR Jupyter Notebook with below code thinking it would read from user(**hadoop**) home directory.

```
sparkify_log_data = "sparkify_log_small.json"
df = spark.read.json(sparkify_log_data)
df.persist()
df.head(5)
```

But when submit the code, i get the below error.

```
'Path does not exist: hdfs://ip-172-31-50-58.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/user/livy/sparkify_log_small.json;'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 274, in json
    return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Path does not exist: hdfs://ip-172-31-50-58.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/user/livy/sparkify_log_small.json;'
```

From googling got to know that YARN default user is **livy**. How can i change the user in the jupyter notebook from livy to hadoop (or) point to the right directory.

I have tried creating a folder like below and copying file from /home/hadoop/sparkify_log_small.json to /home/livy/sparkify_log_small.json

but did not work.

Here basically i am trying to read a file from ec2-master from notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Below procedures resolved it,

**Checked hadoop files**

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

**Created folder in hadoop filesystem**

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /home
hdfs dfs -mkdir /home/hadoop
```

**Copied file to that location**

```
hadoop fs -put ./sparkify_log_small.json /home/hadoop/sparkify_log_small.json
```

Then ran the python code in jupyter cell. It worked.